# Why do I get an ESLint error when I use Angularfire query

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, eslint, angularfire2, angularfire

I am using Angularfire (@angular/fire) to get data from Firestore like this:

```
return this.afs.collection('payments', (ref) => {
  return ref
    .where('group', '==', group)
    .orderBy('category', 'asc');
}).valueChanges();
```

When I check my code with ESLint I get the following error:

> Unexpected block statement surrounding arrow body; move the returned
> value immediately after the `=>`  arrow-body-style

Is there any way to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

ESLint is basically complaining you have a block you aren't otherwise using. If you change it to the following short-hand it should be happy:

```
return this.afs.collection('payments', ref =>
  ref
    .where('group', '==', group)
    .orderBy('category', 'asc')
).valueChanges();
```

Note the drop of the curly braces and return.

FWIW this is the type of error that ESLint should be able to fix itself, just pass `--fix` to your ESLint command and it will fix issues that it knows how to.